# how to open bottomSheet after navigate on the page without using onPressed flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it possible to open bottomSheet after navigate the page without using onPressed?

Currently, I added to open `bottomSheet` on `onPressed` event

```
scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) => Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
)),
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've tried this already but you could define a stateful widget and add your function that shows the bottomSheet to it's state, I've added a sample bellow,

```
void _modalBottomSheetMenu() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) {
            return new Container(
              height: 350.0,
              color:
                  Colors.transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373),
              //so you don't have to change MaterialApp canvasColor
              child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                  )),
            );
          });
    });
  }
```

That will wait for the first frame to be drawn before showing the bottomSheet, therefore you can call it from initState

@overrideand in the init state you'll call the above function.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _modalBottomSheetMenu();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add it on `initState()` because at that time you do not have the context yet.

The easiest way to do it is to add a variable `didOpenModalBottomSheet = false` in the beginning

Then in the build add something like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(!didOpenModalBottomSheet){
        didOpenModalBottomSheet = true;
        _modalBottomSheetMenu();
    }
    return ...
```

You could also use this library: https://pub.dev/packages/need_resume
specialy if you are coming from Android. But I did not try it yet.

Comment: I guess you didn't try running the accepted solution before posting your own answer. It really worked as expected.